# Character mesh low poly in object mode and high poly in sculpt mode

Tags: mesh

I used InstantMeshes to clean the high poly character 3D scan object, which had to much vertices to be practical.

Now I want to adjust the muscle structure with sculpt mode, and I noticed that the mesh was low poly in object mode when I import it into blender. And high poly in sculpt mode, so I'm wonder what I did wrong or something else.

What should I do ? How to make the mesh in object mode look like high poly ?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about this,
But it looks to me like simply right clicking no the object and clicking 'Shade Smooth" while in object mode should do the job

Comment: I didn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind I did find the issue. I uncheck "Auto Smooth" in the Object Data Propreties